How to apply a minecraft skin texture to my model and add the outer layer to the model?
I want to add minecraft skin model to my website using three.js:

I'm using next.js, so to interact with three.js I use @react-three/fiber and @react-three/drei.
I just started learning three.js and tried to create a skin model. Here's what I did:

Here is the code for this model:
<Canvas>
        <OrbitControls enableRotate={true} autoRotate={true} />
        <ambientLight intensity={1} />
        <directionalLight color="white" position={[0, 0, 5]} />
        <group position={[0, 1.5, 0]}>
        <mesh>
            <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial color="green" />
        </mesh>
        <mesh position={[0, -1.375, 0]}>
            <boxGeometry args={[0.5, 1.75, 1]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial color="red" />
        </mesh>
        <mesh position={[0, -1.375, 0.75]}>
            <boxGeometry args={[0.5, 1.75, 0.5]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial color="white" />
        </mesh>
        <mesh position={[0, -1.375, -0.75]}>
            <boxGeometry args={[0.5, 1.75, 0.5]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial color="blue" />
        </mesh>
        <mesh position={[0, -3.125, 0.25]}>
            <boxGeometry args={[0.5, 1.75, 0.5]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial color="yellow" />
        </mesh>
        <mesh position={[0, -3.125, -0.25]}>
            <boxGeometry args={[0.5, 1.75, 0.5]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial color="gray" />
        </mesh>
        </group>
    </Canvas>

How can I now add minecraft skin textures with an outer layer to my model? If it is difficult to display the outer layer, then simply use the inner layer of the skin from a similar skin file:

I found this repository on the Internet https://github.com/bs-community/skinview3d
I tried in every possible way to adapt it to my code (I use next.js, but here use regular html and three.js, and not @react-three/fiber and @react-three/drei). But I was never able to display the slightest pixel.

Loading skinViewer.playerObject into a Three.js scene causes texture loading issues. Since skinview3d is built on top of Three.js, it provides a solid foundation. You can continue working by adding new objects to skinview3d.scene.
